# Cannot install scipy, numpy or pandas with pip

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I am trying to install pandas, numpy and scipy on a 64 bit windows machine.  I tried the general pip install numpy and the same for scipy and pandas, but the download fails every time.  I then tried to download the .whl files from Christoph Gohlke's web page http://www.ifd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ (I hope i typed the address correctly).  I can download the libraries from his page and they do sucessfully install when using the pip command, but any .py file that imports them fails when I try to run the file.  I have tried to run on command prompt and cygwin and the result is the same every time.  I get the following errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

If anybody knows wht might be causing my Python installation and use problems I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy do you try this?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.16.2/

Comment: See http://www.scipy.org/install.html. They recommend you to install one of the scientific Python distributions. I installed Anaconda and it works quite fine in W7/64. Good luck.

Comment: Did you get the correct files?  You say you're on 64-bit Windows, but is your *Python* install also 64-bit?  (You can have 32-bit Python on 64-bit Windows.)

Comment: Yes it was a 64 bit file I installed.  I have not tried Anaconda, I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. There is only one version of python installed 3.5.0 and i am trying numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl. Please let me know if you have been able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Installing *NumPy*, *SciPy*, and *pandas* with precompiled .whl binaries would avoid this problem entirely.

Just be sure you are installing the correct files with pip.

Also if you have several versions of Python installed, be sure you are running your .py file on the version of Python that you installed *NumPy*, *SciPy*, and *pandas* into.

---

download:  **numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl**
from:  [lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

and

download:  **scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl**
from  [lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)

and

download:  **pandas-0.17.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl**
from  [lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas)

---

I installed these with pip on a fresh install of Python 3.5.0 and had no problems.

---

Install in the order listed below:

```
python -m pip install numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

python -m pip install scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

python -m pip install pandas-0.17.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

---

After installing I then ran the following imports in a .py file successfully:

```
import scipy
import numpy
import pandas
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but a download and install from the gohlke web site was the first thing I tried and it does not work.  For reasons that I do not understand I get the message that the numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.  I am making the download for Python 2.7.10.  And I have a Visual C++ compiler already installed, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: are you using a amd processor, im using a atom processor. where would you download this, in the python35(for me its python34) from the C drive. and which folder?